# what is the use of settings.Modal = true; in Devexpress MVC PopUpControl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, popup, devexpress

Actually i am using DevExpress MVC Extensions and in that i am using PopUpControl.
while going through the demo's i found out a statement like

```
settings.Modal = true;
```

Can any one tell me the actual use of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `settings.Modal = true;` it will consider this dialog as modal dialog